# What is the industry term for those "earn credit by affiliates" programs in iPhone/Android/etc games?

Tags: android, iphone, terminology, marketing, android-market

In iPhone, Android, and other gaming platforms you can sometimes earn credit by installing other games, going to someones website, even signing up for a credit card.

For iPhone, for example, there are entire networks set up for this kind of affiliate marketing.

What is the industry term for this?

Comment: I think the word you're looking for is "Scams" - sorry, couldn't resist.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. The term I was looking for is "Cost per Install", or the related field of "Cost per Action" marketing.